# Deleting files or group in Xcode Project using AppleScript or programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, applescript

First and foremost, the objective I am trying to achieve here is to delete some of the files in Xcode projects that are not required, using automation.

I have tried using AppleScript to launch Xcode and command it to delete certain files, but no success so far, below is my AppleScript for the deletion

```
tell application "Xcode"
    open ("/Users/bulbasaur/Desktop/ios/Tutorial.xcworkspace")
    set testproject to project "Tutorial"
    tell testproject
        set rootgroup to group "Tutorial-iPhone"
        tell rootgroup
            delete file reference "main.h" of group "Classes"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

i got an error of

```
error "Xcode got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

so the question is,

1. Is there any mistake that I did in my AppleScript? and how can i correct it?
2. Is there any alternative in deleting Xcode's project files programmatically? Maybe via some sort of command in terminal?

Note that deleting via Finder or Terminal does not work well as Finder does not delete the reference link in Xcode Project(project.pbxproj)

Answer (score 0):

I did not check all your script, but, first, change the Open file path to use Finder path and not Unix path :

```
open ("Users:bulbasaur:Desktop:iOS:Tutorial.xcworkspace")
```

for the rest, please open Applescript Editor, add Xcode to your Applescript library, and you will see all possible AS instructions for xCode.

Comment: Hi @pbell i have change the file path to as you suggest, and also added Xcode to my library (via Windows>Library). 

I tried deleting the file via this code

'set testproject to project "Tutorial"
 tell testproject
  set rootgroup to group "Tutorial"
  tell rootgroup
   delete file reference "temp.h" of rootgroup
 end tell
end tell'

but no breakthrough so far.. haha... pls advice ^.^

Comment: also i change the code to 'delete "temp.h" of root group' and got an error of "Can’t get "temp.h" of rootgroup. Access not allowed." any ideas?